# Badge Tracking - Wrong indication

Tags: discussion, badges

[image]

The image says my question .

The requirement to get `Curious badge` is fulfilled . But still it is tracking for `Curious badge` .

Is this normal behavior ?

Comment: There are two parts to Curious. Perhaps you've not fulfilled the second part?

Comment: He was not enough curious to see the definition of "Curious".